# Rake task selectivly ignoring new code

Tags: ruby, debugging, rake, rake-task, openbsd

In a rake task I'm writing some puts statements show changes while others don't. For instance changing

```
puts model+" | "+id
```

into

```
puts model+" * "+id
```

doesn't change in the output of the script. However in some places changing

```
puts "Connecting to "+site
```

into

```
puts "Connecting to ----"+site
```

shows the changes that where made.

In the places where any changes to the line doesn't change the output, adding a new puts statement before or after don't show up when the task is run. Commenting out lines of code around the unchanging puts statements that do the actual work cause the script to not execute those lines, just as it should, but changing or adding puts statements there do not change the output of the script.

Removing all other tasks and emacs backup files from the lib/tasks folder doesn't help. I've been bitten before by having a backup copy of a task with the same namespace and task name running instead of the one I was working on.

This is being run with Ruby 2.4.3 on OpenBSD 6.3-stable on a fx-8350. I would post the whole script but the company I'm working for won't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

How about

`puts "#{model} +/*/whatever #{site}"`

It shouldn't matter to what sounds like a filesystem update issue (reboot), but it's probably better form to put the variables in the string like that instead of + "" them.

Comment: I tried changing it into a single string like you suggested but it still shows the output as if nothing had been changed. I'd already tried rebooting once but I don't think it's a filesystem issue since I can look at the file in other programs and can see the changes, and some changes to the script do show up when it's changed. All of the task is in one file. I know the functions are being called because the work on the data is being done and removing any of those lines to cause them to not be run. However adding a 'raise model.inspect' or 'exit' before the puts statement doesn't stop it.

Comment: Me too, in the 18 years I've been coding I've never come across something this bizarre. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: I've seen weird filesystem things.  I've also updated methods and not had them update only to find out they were redefined later.
Maybe add byebug and a breakpoint to make sure that you're really executing what you think you are.  And/or that something insane hasn't happened - like puts being modified to replace all '*' with '|'.